# Calculate the flux of a field through a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Given the surface $S\{(z,y,z)\in \mathbb{R} | x^2+y^2=1, 0\leq z\leq 1\}$ and the vectorial fields $X(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}(x,y,0)$ and $Y(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{(x-3)^2+y^2}(x-3,y,0)$ I have to calculate the flux of both vectors fields through $S$

I have calculated the divergence of $X$ and $Y$, and they are both $0$

So $$\int_S divXdV=\int_S divYdV=0$$

However when I calculate $$\int_{\partial S} \langle F·N \rangle dS$$ does not give me $0$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your flux integral is over $S$, not over $\partial S$. The triple integrals need to be over a 3-dimensional region $V$ with $\partial V = S$. Here is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your surface is not closed, and so it doesn’t bound a volume to which you can apply the Divergence Theorem.  Add on the disks and see what happens.

Comment: For the vector field $X$, I think the bigger issue is the denominator $\dfrac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$, which means along the $z$-axis, the denominator is $0$, so the vector field is not even defined. So, I doubt it is even meaningful to talk about the integral $\int_S \text{div}(X) \, dV$, let alone apply the divergence theorem in this situation (atleast the standard version, which I know of, where everything is nice and smooth and well-defined). ($S$ being the solid cylinder with caps rather than the hollow one which the OP described)

Comment: @peek-a-boo: I confess I didn't even look at the vector fields. Yes, the divergence theorem definitely won't apply to vector field $X$, although it tells you — and you can check directly — that the flux outwards across the cylinder $x^2+y^2=a^2$, $z_1\le z\le z_2$, is $2\pi(z_2-z_1)$, independent of $a$.